# Receiving incoming mail content with imapclient

Tags: python, imapclient

I am using ImapClient. I cannot read the content of the incoming message.
How can I read the message content, time and who it came from?

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
import email

HOST = 'imap.gmail.com'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

server = IMAPClient(HOST)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
server.select_folder('INBOX')

# Start IDLE mode
server.idle()
print("Connection is now in IDLE mode, send yourself an email or quit with ^c")

while True:
    try:
        # Wait for up to 30 seconds for an IDLE response
        responses = server.idle_check(timeout=10)
        print("Server sent:", responses if responses else "nothing")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

server.idle_done()
print("\nIDLE mode done")
server.logout()
```

Comment: In what way is your code failing?

Comment: it's actually not failing.
I just can't get the incoming mail content.